# Checking for Item in a List Box Ignoring Case

Tags: string, vb.net, listbox, case-insensitive

Having an issue with a bit of code designed to add an email alias to a list box. I have a check built in to ensure the item you attempt to add isn't already in the list, but the check is case sensitive when I don't want it to be. I'm not sure how to make it ignore the case... Here's my code:

```
Dim ItemToAdd as String = ""

ItemtoAdd = tbxItemtoAdd.Text + "@emaildomain.co.uk"

If Not lbxEmailAliases.Items.Contains(ItemtoAdd) Then
    lbxEmailAliases.Items.Add(ItemtoAdd)
End If
```

At the moment if the list box contains **johnsmith24**@emaildomain.co.uk and you try to add **Johnsmith24** (capital J), it will add this successfully, but I don't want it to do that. How do I get it to ignore case?

I've tried changing `lbxEmailAliases.Items.Contains(ItemtoAdd)` to `lbxEmailAliases.Items.Contains(ItemtoAdd, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` but it's not happy with this as there are too many arguments, it will only take one.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is a standard WinForm `ListBox` control, then there is no way to do it without looping through all of the items and checking each one individually.  For instance:

```
Dim found As Boolean = False
For Each item As Object In ListBox1.Items
    found = item.ToString().Equals(ItemToAdd, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    If found Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If found Then
    lbxEmailAliases.Items.Add(ItemtoAdd)
End If
```

However, if you are comfortable with LINQ, you can do it more concisely like this:

```
If ListBox1.Items.OfType(Of String).Any(Function(item) item.Equals(ItemToAdd, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) Then
    lbxEmailAliases.Items.Add(ItemtoAdd)
End If
```

Or, as Andy G pointed out, the LINQ `Contains` method is even easier since it accepts an `IEqualityComparer` and a stock one which supports case insensitive string comparisons is provided by the framework:

```
If ListBox1.Items.OfType(Of String).Contains(ItemToAdd, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
    lbxEmailAliases.Items.Add(ItemtoAdd)
End If
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

It should be `StringComparer`, not `StringComparison`:

```
lbxEmailAliases.Items.Contains(ItemtoAdd, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

The method accepts an `IEqualityComparer`, [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118.aspx).

As pointed out by Steven Doggart, ListBox Items require the use of OfType(Of T):

```
lbxEmailAliases.Items.OfType(Of String).Contains(ItemtoAdd, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Nice, however, it's worth mentioning that if it is a WinForm `ListBox`, the `Items` property only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable(Of T)`, so most of the LINQ methods are unavailable until after calling `OfType(Of T)` or `Cast(Of T)`.

Comment: Thank you. (I tested briefly in LINQPad with a string array.)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative could be the [`FindString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/e5et1818(v=vs.110).aspx)-method:

```
If lbxEmailAliases.FindString(ItemtoAdd) = ListBox.NoMatches Then
    lbxEmailAliases.Items.Add(ItemtoAdd)
End If
```

**Note**: This method searches for items that start with the specified string and returns the index of the first found item.
Means it will find `jdoe@domain.com` even if the existing e-mail-address is `jdoe@domain.computer.com`.

So maybe it's not the best solution for your specific case.

**EDIT:**

You can use [`FindStringExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.findstringexact(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. Like this you'll get the wanted case insensitive, non-partial comparison.

```
If lbxEmailAliases.FindStringExact(ItemtoAdd) = ListBox.NoMatches Then
    lbxEmailAliases.Items.Add(ItemtoAdd)
End If
```

Comment: Nice, I forgot all about that method.  Actually, if you use `FindStringExact` it won't find partial matches.  Despite the misleading name `FindStringExact` is also case-insensitive.  I guess that's my only concern with these methods--the case-insensitivity isn't obvious to the casual observer.  Well, that and the lack of control over the precise nature of the comparison (e.g. current-culture vs. invariant-culture).

Comment: @StevenDoggart Thanks for your comment. I didn't realize that `FindStringExact` is case-insensitive too